# Change Color of Point Object Using QtGui.QPainter() in Python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm developing a map visualization program in Python using several modules from qtpy.  There is a main window interface which displays a background map containing several geolocated points on the screen.  The location of each point is determined by an external .csv file that has information regarding the latitude, longitude, and other text attribution.  This file gets read-in by the program each time the map window is instantiated.  The color of each point defaults to red when the map window is opened, but I would like to have each point change to a different color based on its metadata stored in the .csv file.  For instance, there is a header in the file called "color", and each point has the text string "red", "green" or "blue" encoded.  Here is the section of code I've been working on so far...

```
# Initialize all points to default color.
color = QtCore.Qt.red

for i, p in zip(range(len(self.points)), self.points):
    if lb_lat <= stn_lat and stn_lat <= ub_lat and window_rect.contains(*self.transform.map(stn_x, stn_y)):
        if p['color'] == 'green':
            color = QtCore.Qt.green
        elif p['color'] == 'blue':
            color = QtCore.Qt.blue
        elif p['color'] == 'red':
            color = QtCore.Qt.red
        else:
            color = QtCore.Qt.white
        qp.setPen(QtGui.QPen(color, self.scale))
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(color))
        qp.drawEllipse(QtCore.QPointF(stn_x, stn_y), size, size)
```

The list of points is stored in the variable self.points and I'm trying to iterate through this list and  apply the correct color to each point using QtGui.QPen and QBrush.  What is happening is that if the color attribute in the .csv file for point 1 has the text string "green", then the entire array of points changes to green instead of just that one point.  Looking at the code after the if...else statements, I haven't been able to find a way to "index" the setPen and setBrush commands for just the point in question.  The coloring methods are acting on the entire array of points as one indivisible unit instead of working on each point separately as intended.  Would anyone perhaps know of a way to do this using the Qt framework?  Please let me know if supplying additional code might help clarify the problem or give better context as I'd be happy to do that.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue I had by removing the looping construct where I was iterating through the items in self.points.  I had a higher-level "for" loop already in place and this was causing the incorrect array index to be referenced each time the points were being drawn to the screen.  Each point is now changing to the appropriate color.